# Odd/even number with the verification of an input

Tags: c#, exception, input

I'm trying to make a simple odd/even number program, but I want to compare did user entered number. When I enter any symbol which is not a number I get second exception, but when I just press enter ie. not giving any value, I still get a second except except the first one, which I'm trying to get when I don't give any value. My question is how to get a first exception text when I just press enter, since right now I only get second one, whatever I enter.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        try
        {
            var number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (number % 2 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is even.");

            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is odd.");
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to enter some value.");
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a number.");
        }
```

Comment: What does your question? By the way, I suggest you read input line, check that it's not empty and then try to parse it

Comment: please be more explicit

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. I want to get first exception text to appear when I just press enter, since right now I always get the second one.

Comment: Console.ReadLine will not return null when input comes from keyboard "If the standard input device is the keyboard, the ReadLine method blocks until the user presses the Enter key."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch `FormatException` in case you just press enter as `string.Empty` is being passed to `int.Parse`. `ArgumentNullException` is being thrown only if the input value which  was passed to `int.Parse` is `null`. Here is example how you can do this and write different messages depending on the inputed value:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    var number = int.Parse(input);
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is even.");

    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is odd.");
}
catch (FormatException exc)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You need to enter some value.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a number.");
    }

}

catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a number.");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, 'FormatException' now catches both letters and when I just press enter. That will do, thanks! Is there a way to show 2 different exceptions, one when user enters something that's not a number and another when just enter is pressed?

Comment: That's it, thank you! I've no idea why my question got downvoted.

Comment: @MarkWest you can show different messages but to throw different exceptions you should implement your own `Parse` method and in that method during validation of the passed value throw different exceptions. `int.Parse` method is not providing different exceptions for the case you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = Console.ReadLine();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need to enter some value.");
}
else
{
    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(str, out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You need to enter a number.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is even.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Entered number {number} is odd.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely works and thank you for that, but I wanted to do it with exceptions.

Comment: @MarkWest Do you know that `try/cath` construction is more slowly than code is above?
If you know it and anyway want to use it, that's your choice.

Comment: I don't really worry about the speed right now. I'm just trying to learn different approaches.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria that's an invalid statement. Try/catch is not by any means slower than anything. Raising exceptions is expensive, yes, but the try/catch block on its own does not add any kind of performance hit.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you want to tell me that `.try` section in IL not slower than, for example, the `ceq`command that compares two values?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enter any value, the value is not **null** but ""(empty string), that's why it's not an **ArgumentNullException**

Do how George Alexandria suggested

```
    string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
if(s == "")
{ Console.WriteLine("You need
    to enter some value."); }
```

Comment: So how can I get edit it to get first exception to work? Using iSNullOrEmpty somehow?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Camilo Terevinto

Comment: You still have a capital I in if, which is invalid C# if im not misstaken

Comment: Oh I&amp;#39;m sorry, auto-capitalization in mobile device, can&amp;#39;t help it but sure gets the message across @kirodge. I edited it fyi

Comment: Yeah, I got the message anyway. Just for completeness since you asked Camilo to elaborate.